# How different would the current situation of South Korea be if Seoul wasn’t 30 miles from the DMZ

Tags: korea

I can’t decide how much more likely war with North Korea would be if South Korea’s largest city and capital were much farther down the peninsula. Whenever tensions rise I hear how vulnerable Seoul is and wonder if it makes the south tolerate the north’s aggressive tantrums more.

Comment: South Korea is a fairly densely populated nation.  If not Seoul, there would be other towns, cities and people near enough to the border to be under threat of North Korean attack.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a counterfactual/alternative history

Comment: No different. North Korea wants control over all of South Korea not just Seoul. The location of the South Korean capital is immaterial to the desires and demands of North Korea.

Comment: How is this question related with History?

Answer (score 2):

I think a better question would be "Did the proximity of Seoul to the DMZ stabilize or destabilize Korea after the Korean War?"

- I'm sure that the US and ROK have constantly updated contingency plans to invade the DPRK. They do not **want** to use them, because the cost/benefit ratio is bad, but they will **have** them just in case. What stops them from going in? DPRK artillery in range of Seoul is surely one factor, but so is the presence of China. If Seoul was safe from tube artillery, that wouldn't make restarting the Korean War safe.
- I'm sure that the DPRK has contingency plans to invade the ROK. They might or might not **want** to use them, but again they **have** them just in case. What stops them from going in? The fear of a combined US/ROK counterstrike, which would probably end with the destruction of the DPRK.

Watching from Europe, sometimes I wonder about *both* sides. Trying to build the higher [flagpole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daeseong-dong#Flagpoles)? [Loudspeakers](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-35278451) with music? The ROK has good reasons to be scared of the DPRK, but if they were *less* scared, we might have had another war by now.